# jQuery Selector with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am looking to scan a page and look for any html elements that have a class or id that contains the word `price`. My thought was to use regex here but I cannot get it to fire correctly.

I am using Safari and Chrome on OS X

```
var price = $("div:regex(\bprice\b)").text();
```

The purpose is to get the price of a product on an e-commerce site if it isn't already stated in Open Graph which is already handled.

Comment: Interesting alternate way of doing this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163888/jquery-get-only-all-html-elements-with-ids   Though may be a perf slug :( But still, interesting.

Answer (score 3):

`"\b"` is same as `"\x08"`.

Escape `\`:

```
var price = $("div:regex(\\bprice\\b)").text();
```

Comment: thanks for this however i am getting this in the console `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: regex`

Comment: `regex` isn't part of jQuery, you have to use http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Comment: Great thanks for this getting this now any thoughts? `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'match[3]')`

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use *contains word selector*:

```
$('div[id~="price"], div[class~="price"]')
```

See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Comment: I have tried using this `$('div[id~="price"], div[class~="price"], span[id~="price"], span[class~="price"], p[class~="price"], p[id~="price"]').first().text();` and it works well however seems a little messy any thoughts?

Comment: So just use `$('[id~="price"], [class~="price"]')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding new pseuo selector:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var regex = new RegExp(match[3]),
        $elem = $(elem);
    return regex.test($elem.attr('class')) || regex.test($elem.attr('id')); 
};
```

and you can use this selector using:

```
$("div:regex(\\bprice\\b)")
```