# How to access arguments in new pseudo selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, pseudo-class

I wanted to create pseudo selector :regex to anwser this question: [jQuery Selector with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527912/jquery-selector-with-regex/18528057) and wanted to write full example but it throw exception

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined
```

My code:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    new RegExp(match[3]);
};
```

and when I do `console.log(arguments)` it only show two arguments element and document, does the API changed or what? How can I access argument to pseduo selector?

Comment: Have you looked at how the `contains` pseudo-selector is implemented in the jQuery source?

Comment: jquery version used? and how the regex is used

Comment: seems to be fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kJ3Tj/1/

Comment: I test on jquery 1.8.0 maybe something is wrong with that version

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for your situation, but I would like to provide it here for future searchers.

```
$.fn.regexFilter = function (expression, flags) {
    flags = flags != null ? flags : "g";

    if (expression.constructor === String) {
        // simple string expression
        expression = new RegExp(expression, flags);
    } else if (expression.constructor === Array) {
        // turns ["a", "b", "c"] into (a)|(b|(c)
        expression = new RegExp("(" + expression.join(')|(') + ")", flags);
    }
    // objects in the form of {expression: "foo", flags: "gim" }
    else if (typeof expression === "object" && expression.foo) {
        expression = new RegExp(expression.expression, expression.flags != null ? expression.flags : flags);
    } else if (expression.constructor !== RegExp) {
        // otherwise we assume no mathes
        return $();
    }

    // list of matches
    var matches = [];

    // list of matching elements
    var $matches = this.filter(function () {
        var haystack = $(this).text();
        var match = haystack.match(expression);

        matches.push(match);
        $(this).data('match', match);

        return !!match;
    });

    $matches.matches = matches;

    return $matches;
};
```

These are all equivalent, and match any `<p>` with a word starting with "c":

```
$('p').regexFilter('\\bc\\w+', 'g').css({
    color: 'green'
});

$('p').regexFilter(/\bc\w/g).css({
    color: 'green'
});

$('p').regexFilter({expression: '\\bc\\w+', flags: 'g'}).css({
    color: 'green'
});
```

You can also retrieve the submatches in any function.  Here we match the first two words.  The second word is stored in group 1.

```
$('p').regexFilter(/^\w+\s(\w+)/).each(function () {
    var match = $(this).data('match');
    var oldText = ["the second word of <i>", $(this).text(), "</i> is", match[1]].join(" ");
    $(this).html(oldText);
});
```

You can also just get the array of matches for all elements.

```
var $matchedElements = $('p').regexFilter(/^\w+\s(\w+)/);
var matches = $matchedElements.matches;
matches[3][1] // the second word of the 4th p
```

Note that this match array doesn't persist, and there will be `nulls` in the array.  So the 4th p is `$(p)[3]`, not `$matchedElements[3]`.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBYnn/2/)

Comment: This is not psedo selector but jQuery plugin. I don't think that will help anybody that search for pseudo selector.