# Tooltipster not working properly in the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tooltipster

I am using the *tooltipster* plugin tool where I got *gantt chart* drawn with some `td` given `id`.
So, which ever `id` is defined and the mouse over it will get *ajax* data and show accordingly.

Below is snippet of my codes. Issue here is that the tool tip only appear after few times I mouse the `td`. Thereafter, it works fine.
I can see, in my debug window, that *ajax* page is called and following error:
`Tooltipster: one or more tooltips are already attached to this element: ignoring. Use the "multiple" option to attach more tooltips. jquery.tooltipster.min.js:1`

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        
      $('td[id]').tooltipster({
    // content: 'Loading...',
     functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
        // We'll make this function asynchronous and allow the tooltip to go ahead and show the loading notification while fetching our data
        continueTooltip();
        var idval=0;
        // Next, we want to check if our data has already been cached
        //if (origin.data('ajax') !== 'cached') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'getDetails.php',
                data:idval,
                success: function(data) {
                    // Update our tooltip content with our returned data and cache it
                    //alert("Data is : "+data);
                    var finalData = 'Total Data : 300 <br> Total Completed : 200';

                    //alert("DATA");
                    //origin.tooltipster: $('<span>testst<strong>This text is in bold case !</strong></span>')

                   origin.tooltipster({
                        content: finalData,
                        multiple: true,
                        contentAsHTML: true
                    });

                    //origin.tooltipster({content: data,contentAsHTML: true}).data('ajax', 'cached');
                }
            });
        //}
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

The Tooltipster plugin really should be initialised before all of this. Using the `mouseenter` enter to trigger it's initialisation every time a user hover's over a `<td>` element is not great practice and is the root problem to your issue. Ideally you would want to break it down into the following:

1. Find your `<td>` elements *with* id's defined.
2. Apply tooltipster to these elements.
3. Let tooltipster handle everything from there.

#### 1. Finding your `<td>` elements

With the magic of jQuery you can fetch these with a clever use of selectors rather than querying a larger set with your initial implementation, gathered from the answers within the StackOverflow thread here, [jquery get only all html elements with ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163888/jquery-get-only-all-html-elements-with-ids), we get:

```
$('td[id]')
```

This will fetch you all `<td>` elements with an id defined, be warned this could be a bit slow if you have an extensive table. Alternatively you can select, then apply a `filter` to narrow down your set:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('id') !== undefined;
});
```

Both will essentially do the same!

#### 2. Applying tooltipster to these elements

I've not done much here since you had a lot of commented out code, so I've kept it the same, with some minor tweaks, here is my version of the "working code":

```
$('td[id]').tooltipster({
    // content: 'Loading...',
   functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
        // We'll make this function asynchronous and allow the tooltip to go ahead and show the loading notification while fetching our data
        continueTooltip();

        // Next, we want to check if our data has already been cached
        //if (origin.data('ajax') !== 'cached') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'getDetails.php',
                data: $(this).attr('id'),
                success: function(data) {
                    // Update our tooltip content with our returned data and cache it
                    //alert("Data is : "+data);
                    var finalData = 'Total Data : 300 <br> Total Completed : 200';

                    //alert("DATA");
                    //origin.tooltipster: $('<span>testst<strong>This text is in bold case !</strong></span>')

                   origin.tooltipster({
                        content: finalData,
                        multiple: true,
                        contentAsHTML: true
                    });

                    //origin.tooltipster({content: data,contentAsHTML: true}).data('ajax', 'cached');
                }
            });
        //}
    }
});
```

#### 3. Letting tooltipster handle everything from here

Tooltipster (when intialised) is triggered by default when hovering over an element, this means your `functionBefore` will be run before this "hover" event, causing your AJAX request to be run each time, there is no need to do anything more thereafter :D

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: I need some clarification how to "initialised before all of this."? What should I do for this? Where to call this $('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('id') !== undefined;
});

Comment: @user2711681 Place the code above within a document ready block, e.g. `$(document).ready(function(){ /** the code goes here **/ });`

Comment: Yes I have done how about this $('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('id') !== undefined;
}); and how to capture the id to be set into my idval variable? I still see its lagging where it need two or three times. I have updates my question with my latest codes.

Comment: @user2711681 That's just an alternative to `$('td[id]')`, you won't need to use it if you're happy with that. You can always set your `idval` using `$(this).attr('id')`, I've updated my answer to reflect this :)

Comment: Ok great it work but I still need at minimum 2 time mouse over then only the tool tip appear. But from the debug log I can see my ajax page is called when I mouse over. Any solution to this?

Comment: @user2711681 Is this a large table with lots of `<td>` elements?

Comment: It is not so many presently. But how to over come this issue any idea please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55522/discussion-between-zesda-and-user2711681).

Comment: hope you are back so any help on how to optimise on my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
var tooltipInstance;
$("body").on('mouseover', 'td[id]:not(.tooltipstered)', function(){
    tooltipInstance = $(this).tooltipster({
        //your code ...
    });
    tooltipInstance.tooltipster('open');
});
```